# Too many re-renders while props location, not using useeffect here

Tags: reactjs

Getting Too many re-renders while switching from one step to another.
In other questions, they are either using setState or useEffect and getting this error. I need to understand my case where I am using none but props where location is being set and I am facing this issue.

```
if (response.success === "true") { gotoStep4(); }

    const gotoStep4 = () => {
        props.history.push({
          pathname: "/subscription",
        });
      };
```

[image]

**I am calling step4 from two places:

1. Steps icon (let's name it: COMPONENT1),
2. another from on success of Step 3(;et' name it: COMPONENT 2)**

For reference, Here is **steps** component(COMPONENT1):

```
class MerchantSteps extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.goToStep3 = this.goToStep3.bind(this);
    this.state = {};
  }

  goToStep4 = () => {
    if (this.props.stepActive === "step2Active" || this.props.stepActive === "step1Active"){
      //Do nothing
          }
          else{
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: "/subscription",
    });}
  };
  goToStep5 = () => {
    if (this.props.stepActive === "step2Active" || this.props.stepActive === "step1Active"){
      //Do nothing
          }
          else{
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: "/complete",
    });}
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wizard-inner">
        <div className="connecting-line"></div>

        <ul className="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li
            role="presentation"
            className={
              this.props.stepActive === "step1Active" ? "active" : "disabled"
            }
          >
         //Steps 1 and 2 here
            <a
              onClick={this.goToStep3}
              href="#step3"
              data-toggle="tab"
              aria-controls="step3"
              role="tab"
              title="Step 3"
            >
              <span className="round-tab">
                <i className="number">3</i>
                <span className="wizard-title">
                  {lang.signpuMerchantStep3Title}
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li
            role="presentation"
            className={
              this.props.stepActive === "step4Active" ? "active" : "disabled"
            }
          >
            <a
            onClick={this.goToStep4}
              href="#step4"
              data-toggle="tab"
              aria-controls="step4"
              role="tab"
              title="Step 4"
            >
              <span className="round-tab">
                <i className="number">4</i>
                <span className="wizard-title">Subscriptions</span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li
            role="presentation"
            className={
              this.props.stepActive === "step5Active" ? "active" : "disabled"
            }
          >
           </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MerchantSteps;
```

COMPONENT 2 where I am calling this is:

```
export default function Merchant3BusinessInformationForm(props) {
  const [responseError, setResponseError] = useState(false);
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
     
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 0) {
      getCategoryList(count);
      // we want to skip validation on first render
      if (firstRender.current) {
        firstRender.current = false;
        if (!!authContext.user) {
          if (!!authContext.user.company_name) {
            setCompanyName(authContext.user.company_name);
            setCategory(authContext.user.business_category);
            setWebsite(authContext.user.website);
            setCountry(authContext.user.country);
          }
        }

        return;
      }
    }
    formValidation();
  }, [companyName, website, country, category]);

  const getCategoryList = (count) => {
    setCount(1);
    authContext.unsetLoader();
    try {
      authContext.setLoader();
      const lang = language;
      const dataBindingToReceiveProductDetails = {
        data: {
          lang: lang,
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_app_store_category",
        success: getCategotyListResultSuccess,
        error: getCategoryListResultError,
      };
      NetworkAdaptation.postData(dataBindingToReceiveProductDetails);
    } catch {
      console.log("something went wrong while fetching data");
      authContext.unsetLoader();
    }
    return;
  };
  const getCategoryListResultError = (response) => {
    authContext.unsetLoader();
    setResponseError(true);
    setMsg({
      title: "Error",
      desc: lang[response.errorcode],
      type: "error",
    });
  };
  const getCategotyListResultSuccess = (response) => {
    authContext.unsetLoader();
    if (response.success === "true") {
      setResponseError(false);
      setCategories(response.data.data);

      console.log("Categories are", categories);
    } else {
      if (!!response) {
        setResponseError(true);
        setMsg({
          title: "Error",
          desc: lang[response.errorcode],
          type: "error",
        });
      } else {
        setResponseError(true);
        setMsg({
          title: "Error",
          desc: lang.signupSomethingWentWrong,
          type: "error",
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const gotoStep4 = () => {
    props.history.push({
      pathname: "/subscription",
    });
  };
  const merchantSignupBusinessInfoSuccess = (response) => {
    console.log("response merchantSignupBusinessInfoSuccess", response);
    if (response.success === "true") {
      authContext.setUser(response.data);
      setResponseError(false);
      gotoStep4();
    } else {
      setResponseError(true);
      setMsg({
        title: "Error",
        desc: lang[response.errorcode],
        type: "error",
      });
    }
  };
  const merchantSignupBusinessInfoError = (response) => {
    setResponseError(true);
    setMsg({
      title: "Error",
      desc: lang.signupNetworkError,
      type: "error",
    });
  };

  const handleBusinessInfoSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("reached handle business info submit");
    const isFormValid = formValidation();

    console.log("errors are: ", businessInfoErrors);
    if (isFormValid) {
      console.log("form is validated");
      if (!!authContext.user) {
        try {
          const merchantBusinessInformationData = {
            data: {
              id: authContext.user.id,
              company_name: companyName,
              website: website,
              business_category: category,
              country: country,
              company_logo: companyLogo,
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_business_info",
            success: merchantSignupBusinessInfoSuccess,
            error: merchantSignupBusinessInfoError,
          };
          //authContext.setloader();
          NetworkAdaptation.postData(merchantBusinessInformationData);
        } catch {
          setResponseError(true);
          setMsg({
            title: "Error",
            desc: lang.dataBindingError,
            type: "error",
          });
        }
      } else {
        setResponseError(true);
        setMsg({
          title: "Error",
          desc: lang.linkInvalid,
          type: "error",
        });
      }
    }
    console.log("isFormValid is", isFormValid);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleBusinessInfoSubmit}>
     //Form rendering done here
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here's step 4 component which's to be rendered but facing error:

```
export default function Merchant4SubscriptionForm(props) {
  const language = "en";
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState(null);
  const [noOfStores, setNoOfStores] = useState(0);
  const [showPriceCalculation, setShowPriceCalculation] = useState(false);
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const primaryDiv = "card rounded bg-primary p-5 my-3 mr-3 text-center";
  const successDiv = "card rounded bg-success p-5 my-3 mr-3 text-center";
  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  const [responseError, setResponseError] = useState(false);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState({
    title: "",
    desc: "",
    type: "",
    callBack: null,
  });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  if (!!authContext.user) {
      setNoOfStores(authContext.user.no_of_store);
      setProductId(authContext.user.subscription_id);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 0) {
      getProductList(count);

      // we want to skip validation on first render
      if (firstRender.current) {
        firstRender.current = false;
        return;
      }
    }
    formValidation();
  }, [productId, noOfStores]);

  const formValidation = () => {
      let valid = true;
    let newErrors = {};
    console.log("form validating");
    if (noOfStores === 0) {
      newErrors.noOfStores = "Please Select a value";
      valid=false;
    }
    if (productId == null) {
      newErrors.product = "Please select a subscription!";
      valid=false;
    }
   
    if(Object.keys(newErrors).length === 0){
        setErrors({});
        console.log("there aren't any errors!");
       valid=true;
    }
    return valid;
  };
  const handleProductSelection = (event) => {
    //debugger
    const product_id = event.target.getAttribute("value");
    setProductId(product_id);

    products.map((product) =>
      product.id === product_id ? setPrice(product.price) : null
    );

    setShowPriceCalculation(true);
  };

  const getProductList = (count) => {
    setCount(1);
    authContext.unsetLoader();
    try {
      authContext.setLoader();
      const lang = language;
      const dataBindingToReceiveProductDetails = {
        data: {
          lang: lang,
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "getSubscriptionPlan",
        success: getSubscriptionPlanSuccess,
        error: getSubscriptionPlanError,
      };
      NetworkAdaptation.postData(dataBindingToReceiveProductDetails);
    } catch {
      setResponseError(true);
      setMsg({
        title: "Error",
        desc: lang.dataBindingError,
        type: "error",
      });
      authContext.unsetLoader();
    }
  };
  const getSubscriptionPlanError = (response) => {
    authContext.unsetLoader();
    setResponseError(true);
    setMsg({
      title: "Error",
      desc: lang.signupNetworkError,
      type: "error",
    });
  };
  const getSubscriptionPlanSuccess = (response) => {
    authContext.unsetLoader();
    if (response.success === "true") {
      setProducts(response.data.data);
    } else {
      if (!!response) {
        setResponseError(true);
        setMsg({
          title: "Error",
          desc: lang[response.errorcode],
          type: "error",
        });
      } else {
        setResponseError(true);
        console.log("test");
        setMsg({
          title: "Error",
          desc: lang.signupSomethingWentWrong,
          type: "error",
        });
      }
    }
  };
  const saveSubscriptionSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isFormValid =  formValidation();
    if (isFormValid) {
      if (!!authContext.user) {
        console.log("user id is", authContext.user.id);
        //console.log("user id data.id is", authContext.user.data.id);
        try {
          const subscriptionInfo = {
            data: {
              id: authContext.user.id,
              subscription_id: productId,
              no_of_store: noOfStores,
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_subscriptions",
            success: savingSubsbscriptionSuccess,
            error: savingSubsbscriptionError,
          };
          NetworkAdaptation.postData(subscriptionInfo);
        } catch {
          console.log("test2");
          setMsg({
            title: "Error",
            desc: lang.signupSomethingWentWrong,
            type: "error",
          });
        }
      } else {
        setResponseError(true);
        setMsg({
          title: "Error",
          desc: lang.linkDirect,
          type: "error",
        });
      }
      
    }
  };

  const gotoStep5 = () => {
    props.history.push({
      pathname: "/merchant-signup-completed",
    });
  };

  const savingSubsbscriptionSuccess = (response) => {
    console.log("response", response);
    if (response.success === "true") {
      setResponseError(false);
      authContext.setUser(response.data);
      gotoStep5();
    } else {
      setResponseError(true);
      setMsg({
        title: "Error",
        desc: lang[response.errorcode],
        type: "error",
      });
    }
  };
  const savingSubsbscriptionError = (response) => {
    setResponseError(true);
    setMsg({
      title: "Error",
      desc: lang[response.errorcode],
      type: "error",
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={saveSubscriptionSubmit}>
       //Form here
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: what happens if you do it like `if (response.success === "true") {   props.history.push({
          pathname: "/subscription",
        }); }`

Comment: @BARNOWL I reach to the same error

Comment: please show more code, the whole method perhaps, and subscription component, and the component from where you're executing this function.

Comment: added more code for reference. I am calling it from two places. one's from on submit and another is from steps icon. The code is similar more or less.

Comment: `console.log("response", response);` what is the result of this console log

Comment: it worked fine previously unless i added merchant steps component where i called the same subscription step. 
response is {"data":{"company_logo":"http://14.99.32.75:902/company//uploads/default_media/avatar.png","id":"5f201efd4d62e97a3a4f99d5","name":"Sakshi","email":"sakshi11@gmail.com","company_name":"dksfj","business_category":"Banking","website":"dksfj","country":"United Kingdom","next_step":"4"},"success":"true","errorcode":"10550"}

Comment: Found the issue, its with setNoOfStores(authContext.user.no_of_store) where the stores haven't been saved yet in authContext in step 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, its with setNoOfStores(authContext.user.no_of_store) where the stores haven't been saved yet in authContext in step 4
Since the value is not there, it goes on in looop to get the value.